# How to get the index count from a DatetimeIndex by given the date?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a DataFrame and its index is the type of DatetimeIndex and it looks as follow:

```
DatetimeIndex(
    ['2003-10-17', '2003-10-21', '2003-10-22', '2003-10-23',
      '2003-10-24', '2003-10-27', '2003-10-28', '2003-10-29',
      '2003-10-30', '2003-10-31',
       ...
      '2017-08-04', '2017-08-07', '2017-08-08', '2017-08-09',
      '2017-08-10', '2017-08-11', '2017-08-14', '2017-08-15',
      '2017-08-16', '2017-08-17'
    ],
    dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name=u'DATE', length=3482, freq=None
)
```

I wonder how to get the position of index-count of `2017-08-04` for example.

Comment: The user had not indent the code part properly so I indent the code part properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get just the integer position of key `'2017-08-04'` use [DatetimeIndex.get_loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.get_loc.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.get_loc) function:

```
dt_idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(
    [ '2003-10-17', '2003-10-21', '2003-10-22', '2003-10-23', '2003-10-24', '2003-10-27',
      '2003-10-28', '2003-10-29', '2003-10-30', '2003-10-31', '2017-08-04', '2017-08-07',
      '2017-08-08', '2017-08-09', '2017-08-10', '2017-08-11', '2017-08-14', '2017-08-15',
      '2017-08-16', '2017-08-17'
     ], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name=u'DATE', length=3482, freq=None)

print(dt_idx.get_loc('2017-08-04'))
```